# IIS 8 cannot install issues

Tags: windows, powershell, server, iis-8

I have an issue regarding installing IIS8 on Windows Server 2012. I followed the tutorial from [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012), but didn't managed to install it, I was returned this error:

> Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. The source files could not be found. Try installing the roles, role services, or features again in a new Add ROles and Features Wizzard session, and on the Confirmatino page of the wizard, click "Specify an alternate source path" to specify a valid location of the source files that are required for the installation. The location must be accesible by the computer account of the destination server.

I need to mention that I have a valid internet connection.

After some research, I've managed to do it from PowerShell (ran as Admin), with the following command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole
```

Have any of you encountered this issue?

Comment: I haven't seen the error with an internet connection, but have on a network share, usually the share changes or permissions on the share are changed. But since it is online connection, my first thoughts are firewall or proxy could be interfering. I am wondering if the install runs as a different system user than your own during its process (like many threading processes do). Then that user might not get to the internet even though you can. Just a thought...

Comment: Search for IIS 7 cannot install posts on the Internet and you will learn the solutions. Well known issues from the start.

Comment: i am facing a similar issue , it gives below error 'the installation of one or more features failed on ,,.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for this: you need to have windows installation DVD or image mounted and try again with installing IIS features. Worked for me.